# What does non-degenerate mean?

Tags: geometry, definition, functional-equations

The context is that $f$ is a real-valued function on a plane such that for every **non-degenerate** square $ABCD$ in the plane, $f(A)+f(B)+f(C)+f(D)=0$.

What does this word mean here? I've found that "in mathematics, a degenerate case is a limiting case in which an element of a class of objects is qualitatively different from the rest of the class and hence belongs to another, usually simpler, class" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics))), but it's still a little unclear to me. Can someone help explain this more simply?

Thanks!
Much appreciated.

Comment: A point is a square with side length 0; I'd guess the author intends to exclude that case.

Comment: Or if A = B and C = D, we'd have a line segment.

Comment: A line is also considered a degenerate rectangle (or square). I guess any rectangle with a zero side.

Comment: Ohh, gotcha, thank you so much. Seemed pretty insignificant, but definitely important. Thanks again.

Comment: So in this context it means specifically that $A, B, C$ and $D$ are four _distinct_ points.

Comment: Just asking, is this problem from Putnam?